# Textfield is clearing on Enter or TAB

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason when I enter a value in the textfiled and hit enter or TAB the value is deleted and does not publish to the text string output. If I change the value to .decimal it works. Thank you for any pointers to fix this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value = 0

    let percentFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.numberStyle = .percent
       
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Value", value: $value, formatter: percentFormatter)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()

            Text("Entered Value \(value).")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, `value` will have an implicit type of `Int` so it may be confusing the formatter, which is explicitly set to use fractional digits. I’d suggest explicitly setting `@State private var value: Double = 0` or `@State private var value = 0.0`

Comment: I made the change, but have the same issue. I closed xcode and restarted my computer. Still same issue.

Comment: It is definitely the formatter that is the problem. Is there a reason you aren't using the built in `TextField` format? That is `TextField("Enter Value", value: $value, format: .percent)`?

Comment: Yes, I always want it to show two decimal places and can not figure out how to do this. I saw posts that suggest using a ZStack, but I am using a ZStack for another feature.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change the *value* variable data type to 'Float' or 'Double'. Then, If you enter number(eg. 35) before percentage(%) then that value immediately reflects in Text(Entered value 0.35). We are using numberStyle = .percent then percentage symbol is necessary at end. I hope this will help you.

In this link screenshot is available.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6PWt.jpg